# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'v' was corrupted

Tags: c++

when i run the code this error message was shown:
    "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'v' was corrupted"

```
int main()
{
    int v;
    int* pointer = &v;
    int *pointer1 = pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *pointer = i;
        pointer++;
    }
    pointer = pointer1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << *pointer << endl;
        pointer++;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
} //The compiler catch error here.
```

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: So, what is your question? Your first cycle blatantly corrupts memory around `v`. In fact, it seems to be deliberately written to corrupt it.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: `pointer++;` advances the pointer by `sizeof(int)` bytes past the address of `v`.

Comment: oh i get it. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int v; // reserved space for 1 integer

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // for the next 5 integers...
{
    *pointer = i; // Write the value of I to the current integer
    pointer++;   // Move to next integer
}
```

So your problem could be solved by:

```
 int v[5];
```

Comment: Or it could be solved by replacing the cycle condition with `i < 1`... There's no way to know the proper solution to the problem without knowning what the OP is really trying to do.

Comment: just try to make an array without using the basic way